# Sentry HTTP API to create an issue within a project via a React Native application

Tags: api, react-native, analytics, crash-reports, sentry

I'm using a native module [react-native-exception-handler](https://github.com/master-atul/react-native-exception-handler) to handle all JS as well as native exceptions in my react-native application.

The primary reason behind this is that my app is an offline first app and I'm logging errors locally on the device.

I am interested in logging my app's errors and crashes on to sentry without wanting sentry to take over the entire exception handling, is that possible and if yes, how can I achieve it? Doesn't Sentry have an HTTP API where I can POST to and create the issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can review the API document.

https://docs.sentry.io/api/

Also you can use React-Native sdk. **My suggestion is to use the sdk.**

https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry

Answer (score -1):

You can log your errors locally into redux, and then use the message interface to send custom events. More information in the docs. https://docs.sentry.io/clientdev/interfaces/message/

You can also use the context interface for sending extra data with each message or error. https://docs.sentry.io/clientdev/interfaces/contexts/

Comment: I understand that I can use the message interface to create custom messages but how to send to Sentry? Some code examples would be really helpful.

Comment: LINK BROKEN. 4 more to go…